# Input string into two dimensional array in java

Tags: java

I am an absolute beginner, I have data input like

```
3
B B S
S B F
B B F
```

3 represents how many lines of characters will be there, and I am trying to put the characters into lines (first line: BBS, second line:SBF, third line: BBF). And I want to use 2D array to do so, how should I do it?
here is my code

```
Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = str.nextInt();
String dice[][] = new String[5][num];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
      dice[i][j] = str.nextLine();
   }
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What problem are you observing?

Comment: You might need to add an extra `str.nextLine()` after initializing array because the first `nextLine()` after `nextInt()` will return empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is close, but you're using `nextLine()` on the Scanner which will consume the entire String data all at once.

I modified your code a little and produced this output:

```
[[B, B, S], [S, B, F], [B, B, F], [3, null, null], [null, null, null]]
```

It's not totally clear what you're trying to do, but I think this should give you some ideas for how to fix it. I changed a few things for this example:

- define the `Scanner` to use the input you've specified (instead of prompting for it)
- rename the `Scanner` variable from `str` to `scanner`; makes the rest of the code more readable
- rename `num` variable to `charactersPerLine`, better readability
- use `scanner.next()` instead of `nextLine()`, that way you'll get "B", then "B", then "S", etc. each as a separate string value
- added a guard if the scanner is empty, then eject; this is probably something you won't need to keep but I added it so my example works
- print the entire array at the end

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("3 B B S S B F B B F 3");
    int charactersPerLine = scanner.nextInt();
    String[][] dice = new String[5][charactersPerLine];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < charactersPerLine; j++) {
            if (!scanner.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
            dice[i][j] = scanner.next();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(dice));
}
```

**Update**:  The newline-delimited input in OP was added after I posted this answer, but it doesn't change the behavior. Whether or not there are newlines, `scanner.next()` will still return the next value. This input – which includes newlines – still produces the same behavior:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("3\n" +
        "B B S\n" +
        "S B F\n" +
        "B B F");
```

Comment: The 4-line input in OP was added after I posted this answer, but it doesn't change the behavior. Whether or not there are newlines, `scanner.next()` will still return the next value. I verified it with my example – pasted in the newline-delimited input data – and it handles it the same as without newlines.

Comment: I see... but somehow I suspect that the number of entries per line is important, or the number of lines ("3 represents how many lines") but question is not really clear about that

Comment: I agree, the number of entries per line is important – from OP: _"3 represents how many lines of characters will be there"_. OP is using that numeric input to specify the length of the sub-arrays, then again to iterate over them.